# Unable to deploy war file on Tomcat 10. Getting this error

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat9

I am trying to access a WAR file which I have added in Tomcat directory and it is throwing this error when deploying the WAR file.

What could have gone wrong?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2517)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:872)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1408)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @LMC We don't need that. The class name in the error message says it all, i.e. that the deployed code is for Servlet 4 API, and Tomcat 10 is Servlet 5 API, which is not backwards compatible. See duplicate link up top.

Comment: @Andreas It's a good reading for a new OP nevertheless.